# How can I hide hAxis labels in Google material bar chart?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I would like to show a stacked bar chart with grouped bars and only one row of horizontal axis labels. From what I found, it is not currently possible to show a stacked `BarChart` with grouped bars using `visualization.BarChart` as of the Google Visualization API v44 , but this is possible with the material `Bar` chart by using the `series` array option.

For example:

```js
google.charts.load('44', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'bar']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Nothing');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Blue');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Blue');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Blue');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Blue');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Blue');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Red');

  data.addRows([
    ['Row 1', 14, 1, 3, 0, 1, 36],
    ['Row 2', 10, 1, 0, 2, 2, 23],
  ]);


  var options = {
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    },
    isStacked: true,
    series: {
      5: {
        targetAxisIndex: 1
      }
    },
    hAxis: {
      viewWindow: {
        min: 0,
        max: 40
      },
      textPosition: 'none',
      ticks: [null],
      title: 'Hide one of the axis values '
    },
    bars: 'horizontal'
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('stacked-grouped-chart'));
  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="stacked-grouped-chart"></div>
```

My problem is that the horizontal axis range/ticks match for both bars, so showing 2 with the exact same tick values on the bottom is redundant. With the non-material `BarChart`, the `textPosition: 'none'` option can be used to hide labels for an axis, [but this option is not currently supported in material bar charts](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143). Is there another way that one of these axis labels/ticks can be hidden in a non-hacky way?

Note that `textPosition` has no effect.

Answer (score 3):

couldn't find a way to hide the tick marks

but you can move them to the top

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('44', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['bar']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Nothing');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Blue');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Blue');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Blue');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Blue');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Blue');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Red');

  data.addRows([
    ['Row 1', 14, 1, 3, 0, 1, 36],
    ['Row 2', 10, 1, 0, 2, 2, 23]
  ]);

  var options = {
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    },
    isStacked: true,
    series: {
      5: {
        axis: 'red'
      }
    },
    axes: {
      x: {
        red: {
          label: '',
          side: 'top'
        }
      }
    },
    hAxis: {
      viewWindow: {
        min: 0,
        max: 40
      },
      title: 'Hide one of the axis values'
    },
    bars: 'horizontal'
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('stacked-grouped-chart'));
  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="stacked-grouped-chart"></div>
```

---

**UPDATE**

another option would be to modify the chart's svg manually,
once the `'ready'` event fires

here, the top labels are hidden when the chart is drawn...

```js
google.charts.load('44', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['bar']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Nothing');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Blue');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Blue');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Blue');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Blue');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Blue');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Red');

  data.addRows([
    ['Row 1', 14, 1, 3, 0, 1, 36],
    ['Row 2', 10, 1, 0, 2, 2, 23]
  ]);

  var options = {
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    },
    isStacked: true,
    series: {
      5: {
        axis: 'red'
      }
    },
    axes: {
      x: {
        red: {
          label: '',
          side: 'top'
        }
      }
    },
    hAxis: {
      viewWindow: {
        min: 0,
        max: 40
      },
      title: 'Hide one of the axis values'
    },
    bars: 'horizontal'
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('stacked-grouped-chart'));
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    $.each($('#stacked-grouped-chart text'), function (index, label) {
      if (parseFloat($(label).attr('y')) < 20) {
        $(label).attr('fill', 'none');
      }
    });
  });
  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="stacked-grouped-chart"></div>
```

Comment: It's definitely an improvement. I'm starting to think this is the closest we will get.

Comment: only other option i can think of would be kind of _hacky_, see __UPDATE__ above...

Answer (score 0):

var options = {
hAxis : {
format : 'none'
}
}